# Name *.bin file after string

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to get a string from the user through stdin and save it to the variable `InputString`, then create a binary file with the same name as the value of `InputString`. This is the code I've written so far:

```
std::string InputString;
getline(std::cin, InputString);

std::cout << InputString << std::endl;

// The code above works.
// Errors start below. :(

void Printi(std::string filename)
{
    std::ofstream Printi(filename".bin");
    Printi((char*)&Hans, sizeof(Person));  // Hans is an instance of my class Person.
    Printi.close();
}

Printi(InputString);
```

I get the following errors (translated into English from my localized compiler):

```
"Printi": Local function definition is not allowed 

Missing ")" (in line std::ofstream Printi..)
```

How can I solve this problem using only standard C++ libraries?

Comment: `filename + ".bin"`.

Comment: Please show us more of the program -- a minimal sample that we can try to compile to show the problem. As it is, it looks like you're defining a function in the middle of another function or else putting code outside a function, which is not allowed (aside from a few special cases which you're surely not using).

Comment: I edited the grammar and style of the question without altering its meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ofstream Printi(filename".bin")` needs to be `std::ofstream Printi(filename + ".bin")`.  The + operator is used to concatenate the strings and append the .bin to the end of what was supplied in the file name.